# Sum of two Complex Roots

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Give the equation:

$z ^ {200} = i+1$

($z$ is a complex number)

How do I proof/disproof the fact that given any $z1$,$z2$ roots of the equation, their sum, $z1+z2$ is also a root.

I tried using $rcis(\theta)$ and couldn't get anywhere..

EDIT:
I defined two different roots, $$z_1=\frac{21}{400} cis (\frac{45}{200}+\frac{360k}{200})$$ $$z_2=\frac{21}{400}cis(\frac{45}{200}+\frac{360p}{200}), p!=kp!=k$$ and couldn't add the $cis + cis$..

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: each root must have length $\sqrt2/400$.

Comment: If $z$ is a root, so is $-z$ but $z-z=0$ is not a root

Comment: "I tried using rcis(θ)" Good idea, how did it go?``

Comment: @Did I failed to add them, the $cos$,$sin$ additions didn't work out for me...

Comment: *Show what you did*, even if you think it didn't work out.

Comment: I defined two different roots, 
$z1=2^{1/400}cis((45/200+360k/200))$
$z2=2^{1/400}cis((45/200+360p/200))$, $p!=k$ and couldn't add the $cis$ + $cis$..

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that this is true for $z_1,z_2$. Put $z=z_1/z_2$. Then $|z|=1$, and if we put $z=u+iv$, $u,v$ real, we have $u^2+v^2=1$. From the equations, we get also $(1+z)^{200}=1$, hence $|1+z|=1$ and $(1+u)^2+v^2=1$. This gives $u=-1/2$, so $v=\pm \sqrt{3}/2$. So $z$ has to be $j=\exp(2i\pi/3)$, or $j^2$. Now $1+z=-j$ or $-j^2$, and this gives for the first choice $(-j)^{200}=j^{200}=1$. As $200=2+3m$, we have then $j^{2}=1$, a contradiction. Same proof for the other case.

Comment: I have no idea how to use the Euler's formula.. (have not learnt it yet).

Comment: In place of $\exp(2 i \pi/3)$ use $\mathrm{cis}(2 \pi/3)$, which is the same thing.